# Что изучать: Delphi или C#?

Tags: c#, delphi

Что понятнее и легче усваиваемое для мозга 14-ти летнего школьника: delphi или C#?

**UPD** Ну, а если судить по развитию, то что быстрее развивается и не превратиться лет через 10 раритетом

Comment: Пусть начнет с HTML+JavaScript+CSS, а потом пересаживается на С#

Comment: @Сахарок, а это каким образом взаимосвязано? Особенно язык разметки и стилей?

Comment: HTML+CSS - просто для общего развития. А собственно JavaScript интересен как потомок Си - довольно прост в освоение не слишком напрягая голову управлением памятью и прочими `фишками` компилируемых языков. А пересаживаться с него на другие Си-языки намного проще чем с того же Delphi.

Comment: Сахарок разрешает приступать к Си :D

Comment: Спасибо Сахарок

Comment: Взгляните на количество страниц в стандартах ISO Pascal и C#. Я бы предпочел Lazarus, если бы не маркетологи из Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая часть вопроса: оба легко усваиваются, c# чуть запутаннее.

Вторая часть вопроса: вероятнее всего Delphi скоро потеряет свой вес полностью.
C# хороший язык у него все больше поддержки, в частности не так давно Microsoft отдала стек (не помню чего) ASP.NET в MONO (относится к веб программированию на C#). Существуют IDE под линукс MonoDevelop например. Можно сказать что сейчас язык сильно распространен и будет только укреплять позиции.

Насчет комментариев насчет Java могу сразу сказать почему не стоит изучать: сейчас Java принадлежит Oracle. То, что оракл сделал с MySQL думаю все знают. Чем то она конечно же хороша, однако я бы поставил на C#. Последний абзац - ИМХО и не является материалом к обсуждению, как и не претендует на истину.

Comment: В прошлом году одному из наших студентов поставили трояк за дипломную работу (это на самом деле катастрофа - позор и студенту, и его руководителю, да еще и на кафедру тень падает). А другой с практически подобной темой нормально защитился на пятёрку. Первый работал с данными на C# и питоне, второй - на Delphi (притом, что для питона существует масса готовых и полуготовых решений в нашей области). Ошибки были банальными: C#  и питон всё-таки не столь жёстко ставят рамки, вот он и наошибался, а ручные тесты не провел. Это не повод сказать, что Delphi лучше, всё зависит от человека и отрасли.

Answer (score 8):

Все зависит от энтузиазма, сил и подобного. Теоретически, можно хоть сразу взяться за более востребованный C#. Но лично мне в 14 лет было трудновато и с Delphi (правда, тогда было плохо с поиском русской информации по нему в инете, как с точки зрения моего умения поиска, так и с точки зрения вообще наличия качественной информации по программированию), так что сейчас я немного жалею, что не знал о том, что можно было не спешить прыгать слишком высоко. Наверняка, если бы я начал с чего-то простого, потом чуть сложнее и тп, я бы быстрее достиг текущего уровня. Плюс я бы натренеровался в том, чтобы быть гибким и легко переучиваться между совсем разными языками (лучшие программисты мира часто говорят, что хороший программист должен учить по одному новому языку в год).

Answer (score 7):

Дело вкуса. Наверняка тут найдутся любители и того и другого, которые будут поливать грязью противоположный язык. Лично я за **Delphi** для первого языка программирование, т.к. **Pascal** (а он в основе Delphi) **создавался для знакомства с ЯВУ**...

Answer (score 4):

А еще в чем-нибудь практика и понимание есть? Если есть - то поймешь и то и другое. А если нет - то трудно сказать. Посмотри на синтаксис, попробуй пописать хеллоуворлды, там уже как пойдет - выберешь. Я в свое время на дух не переносил С-подобные языки и писал на Delphi. Потом ничего, отпустило.
А еще есть вопрос востребованности программистов C# vs Delphi (как и любой холивар) - субъективное мнение и беглый взгляд показывают, что C# востребованнее.

Comment: Ну насчёт востребованности это мне не интересно если и буду выбирать работу то только связанную с веб программированием.  Ну, а какой из них более понятен, например что бы  для каждого действия как в C# и т.п. не нужно было подключать сотни библиотек

Comment: Сотни библиотек нигде подключать не нужно, лишь необходимые модули :) В Delphi тоже их подключать надо. C# в веб-программировании немало востребован - есть ASP.NET. Преимущество Delphi - перетащил компоненту на форму - IDE сама импортнула модуль. А так все равно - взглянешь вверх, а там uses

Comment: > Преимущество Delphi - перетащил компоненту на форму - IDE сама импортнула модуль

Delphi это не только программирование мышью.

Answer (score 2):

C# -- инструмент более-менее цельный, тогда как delphi -- жуткая эклектика, в которой очень легко запутаться (что-то из паскаля, что-то из Си, что-то из модулы, что-то объедко-ориентированное). Как пела А.Б. Пугачёва "Я тебя слепила из того, что было..."

Comment: > Как пела А.Б. Пугачёва "Я тебя слепила из того, что было..."
Справедливости ради, надо заметить, что это песня А. Апиной, а не А. Б. Пугачевой.

Comment: @atwice Каюсь, певиц мог и перепутать. Но вот шедевры тр. паскаля

   Var arr: array[1..10] of Real;
   Procedure P(a: array of Real);
   Var i: Integer;
   Begin
     For i: = 0 To 9 Do Write(a[i]);
   End;
   Begin
     ...
     P(arr);
   End.

А сишная арифметика указателей, а unit Strings (для null-terminated строк)... Знатоки могут назвать ещё много чего...

Comment: @alexl А что не так в этом коде паскаля? )

Comment: @IVsevolod в коде вроде всё так. В "паскале" не так. Разные диапазоны индекса в вызывающей программе и процедуре.